# Contact form 7 go button not working

Tags: wordpress

I have designed this website http://faitmaisoncuisine.com. On the index page there is subscribe to newsletter. The go button is not clickable while it works when you press enter on keyboard. It is something to do with css. I spent 2 days on it and can't find the solution.
Can you please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: The button works on Chrome.

Comment: Not for me. Badr Hari. Please note I meant the upper one, not the one in footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this part of the code:

```
<div class="grid-12">
    <p class="h1">Our Offerings</p>
    <p class="homeOffering">Fait Maison is a creative catering concept based in Dubai that also offers innovative tailor made plans to suit the bio-individuality of each person.</p>
</div>
```

CSS for these elements:

```
.h1 {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #946c60;
    margin-top: -80px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 1px;
}

.homeOffering {
    padding: 50px 421px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
```

The problem is caused by the following: You gave a -80px margin to the `.h1` paragraph, and that causes the newsletter box to be overlapped by the `.h1` paragraph.

What you need to do (without redoing the entire layout) is:

- Change the div class from `grid-12` to `grid-8`
- Change the right margin of the `.homeOffering` paragraph from `421px` to something around `50px`, so you can get the original paragraph layout back.